# show only matched strings - grep

Tags: regex, grep

I have two files. File1 is as follows

```
Apple
Cat
Bat
```

File2 is as follows

```
I have an Apple
Batman returns
This is a test file.
```

Now I want to check which strings in first file are not present in the second file. I can do a `grep -f file1 file2` but thats giving me the matched lines in the second file.

Comment: The title is a bit confusing. Try making more clear that you want to show lines that are **not** in file2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the strings that are **in the first file and also in the second file**:

```
grep -of file1 file2
```

The result (using the given example) will be:

```
Apple
Bat
```

To get the strings that are **in the first file but not in the second file**, you could:

```
grep -of file1 file2 | cat - file1 | sort | uniq -u
```

Or even simpler (thanks to @triplee's comment):

```
grep -of file1 file2 | grep -vxFf - file1
```

The result (using the given example) will be:

```
Cat
```

---

From the `grep` *man* page:

> **-o**, **--only-matching**
>   Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

From the `uniq` *man* page:

> **-u**, **--unique**
>   Only print unique lines

Comment: The latter could ve simplified to just `grep -of file1 file2 | grep -vxFf - file1`

Comment: While I think the approach is nice, it is a bit overkilling to open files twice to do the checking. I admit I also did in my first solution, but if performance is important, our attempts are going to be very "expensive" :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show words from file1 that are not in file2, a dirty way is to loop through the words and grep silently. In case of not match, print the word:

```
while read word
do
    grep -q "$word" f2 || echo "$word"
done < f1
```

To match exact words, add `-w`: `grep -wq`...

#### Test

```
$ while read word; do grep -q "$word" f2 || echo "$word"; done < f1
Cat
$ while read word; do grep -wq "$word" f2 || echo "$word"; done < f1
Cat
Bat
```

A better approach is to use awk:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i in a) delete a[$i]}} END {for (i in a) print i}' f1 f2
Cat 
Bat
```

This stores the values in file1 into the array `a[]`. Then, it loops through all lines of file2 checking each single element. If one of them matches a value in the array `a[]`, then this element is removed from the array. Finally, in the `END{}` block prints the values that were not found.